# Split layer with lines or with Polygonize (and keeping all features intact) - QGIS 3.18

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, line, splitting, polygonize

I want to divide a polygon layer into different smaller polygons.
I started by converting the main polygon into a line, then I used the `Add line feature` to draw the lines. Then I used the `Split with lines` from the toolbox.
However, it didn’t split them all as you can see. (Probably because not all the lines 'intersect or touch the original polygon line)

Lines Layer:
[image]

Split layer: (I even tried Dissolve first)
[image]

I also tried using the `Polygonize` in the Processing Toolbox. It does not split the existing polygon but creates a new layer with all the polygons which are enclosed by the lines of the another. It is fine with me, but the fields in the attribute table were empty even though I chose `Keep fields from input layer` like this (the first table is from the Polygonize tool, the second one from the original lines layer

[image]

How can

Comment: You could `join attributes by location` afterwards.

Comment: and the answer was just simple as that!
But why the split by lines didn't work? is it because the lines don't intersect with the original polygon as I suspect?

Comment: Maybe because you didn't dissolve the lines before splitting.

Comment: I also try it, same results. Anyhow, `Polygonize` solved the issue but the attributes disappearing was problematic

Comment: Geoprocessing tool `Union` should also do the job, without first converting to lines - just big polygon + smaller polygons as input layers.

Comment: True but all polygons will have the same feature (and same id) right?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `Polygonize` with `join attributes by location` is a workaround!